# Select a table based on input condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g and i need to write a query where in the table that is to be considered for producing the output is based on the user input.

i have written in the following manner, but getting  an error.

```
UNDEFINE CDR
SELECT F.EMPLOYEE_ID FROM
( SELECT DECODE(&&CDR,25,'TABLE 1' ,22,'TABLE 2' ,19,'TABLE 3' ,16,'TABLE 4') FROM DUAL ) F
WHERE F.FLAG='G';
```

Comment: I am getting "F"."FLAG": invalid identifier  ... what i will be needing is employee_id from table 1 if the input from user is 25 and so on ..

Comment: There is no column or alias called `FLAG` in your sub-query. And what are you trying to achieve? Using table_name dynamically?

Comment: yes i am trying to use table name dynamically .. and the sub query should be able to select the corresponding table based on the value of input. is it possible ?

Comment: No. Not possible in SQL. You need to (ab)use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The closest that you can come without dynamic SQL is:

```
select EMPLOYEE_ID
from table1
where flag = 'G' and &&CDR = 25
union all
select EMPLOYEE_ID
from table2
where flag = 'G' and &&CDR = 19
union all
select EMPLOYEE_ID
from table4
where flag = 'G' and &&CDR = 16
union all
select EMPLOYEE_ID
from table1
where flag = 'G' and &&CDR not in (25, 19, 16)
```

Comment: :) , that query was a part of a larger query i was writing.  i will be requiring to join this table with other tables .. any ways thanks for the idea ..